# SpringBoot Exception: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException on an Ajax post request

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2.5.1, Lombock 1.18.20 and jQuery 3.5.1. I need to validate a DTO (with a list as param) via Ajax request. I'm trying to make this request, but I'm getting this error

> m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]]

JavaScript file:

```
const validate = async () => {
    const l1 = {
        field1: 'l1',
        field2: 'l2'
    }
    
    const l2 = {
        field1: 'l3',
        field2: 'l4'
    }
    
    const list = [l1, l2];
    
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify({
        field1: 'valu1',
        field2: 'valu2',
        field3: 'valu3',
        list: list
    });
    
    const formData = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
    formData.append('request', dataJSON);
    
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/mypath/validate',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,        
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        traditional: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //Do something
        }
    });
}
```

Ajax (jQuery) request:

```
-----------------------------996071269515593120684095564
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request"

{"field1":"valu1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3","list":[{"field1":"l1","field2":"l2"},{"field1":"l3","field2":"l4"}]}
-----------------------------996071269515593120684095564--
```

DTO class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@GroupSequence({RequestDTO.class, L1.class, l2.class, L3.class})
public class RequestDTO {
    @NotEmpty(groups = L1.class, message = "This field is required")
    private String field1;
    
    @NotEmpty(groups = L1.class, message = "This field is required")
    private String field2;
    
    @NotEmpty(groups = L2.class, message = "This field is required")
    private String field3;

    @Valid
    private List<RequestListDTO> list;
    
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class RequestListDTO{
        @NotEmpty(groups = L3.class, message = "This field is required")
        private String field1;
        
        @NotEmpty(groups = L3.class, message = "This field is required")
        private String field2;  
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionScope
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypath")
*@Validated I have tried adding this but it doesn't work either*
public class ValidateController {
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/validate", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> validate(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO request) {
        if (request != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(request);
        }       
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I change my controller method to `public ResponseEntity<?> validate(HttpServletRequest request)`, I get the data correctly and can parse it, but I need the first approach

Any idea what's wrong here?